# How to export a 3D Matchmoved camera?

Tags: tracking

I used the Blender Tracker to create a 3D Camera solve and need to export it to another 3D package but can't seem to figure out how.

Neither FBX nor Alembic take the animated camera with it.

Comment: FBX will allow the animated camera. Please describe how you are creating the FBX.

Comment: I'm assuming it has to do with the fact the camera doesn't have keyframes, but has a Motion Tracker Constraint. The problem is, when I click the button to make into F-curve I get an instant freeze up every time.